# IntelliSense / Suggestions: Fulltext search instead of word-based search

Tags: visual-studio-code

Intellisense is not considering all characters and therefore is not showing all functions/vars/tags/.../ that are available. Let me give you two gif examples.

[1st example, HTML, click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZYOp.gif): **<title>** is suggested when the word **title** was typed, but it is not suggested when the words **itle** or **<itle** were typed.

In JS it is also not what I would expect.

[2nd example, JS, click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy18V.gif): when the word **timeout** is typed, it suggests the function **setTimeout**. But there is another function **settimeout**, which actually is a snippet, so it is more valuable for me than the suggested one. **settimeout** even has a short description right next to it **Set Timeout Function**. Would be nice to search that description too.

It seems to be that VS Code is looking for words instead of all chars when suggesting functions/vars/tags/.../. I found 2 settings to play with, but they didn't change anything.

```
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
"editor.suggest.showWords": false
```

Is there a way to turn the suggestion feature the way I want to have it?